# いかんでは why is this answer incorrect?

Tags: grammar

最近とても疲れやすいので、その日の体調いかんでは________

I answered it with : 会社を休むこともある

But got it wrong(got 0 points), with a note telling me to use かもしれない instead.

I understand that you can answer with the かもしれない format, but wonder why こともある is incorrect.

These are examples I took from the internet :

金額いかんでは、その仕事を引き受けないこともありません。

裁判の判決いかんでは、控訴することもあり得る。

わたしの帰宅時間は毎日違う。日によっては夜中になることもある。

Basing from these, I think it's safe to assume my answer is not wrong...

---

Edit:
I went and asked my teacher, and although I don't understand the whole explanation, I think I can understand why my answer might not be correct :

The said sentence has a reasoning clause which is **最近**とても疲れやすいので. It would only make the most sense when the line is told to your co-worker, or family with the goal to inform in advance; In the near future, you might take a day off depending on your physical condition.

I guess it's similar to saying 明日の天気によっては、試合が中止になることもある where tomorrow's match is a one-time thing. The こともある hinted multiple occurrences in the past and the coming future. They don't match, so saying 明日の天気によっては、試合が中止になるかもしれない is better.

If 最近 is replaced with words to mean like ずっと生まれから疲れがちなので, then こともある will be correct.

Comment: I think your answer is not unnatural.

Comment: So... I mentioned this on the chat too, and AFAIK at least four people on this site including me feel that your answer is valid. Maybe you can ask your teacher what they think if possible.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. 最近とても疲れやすいので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともある。
> 2. 最近とても疲れやすいので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともあるかもしれない。
> 3. ずっと前から疲れがちなので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともある。
> 4. ずっと前から疲れがちなので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともあるかもしれない。

1と2を比べたとき1より2の方が自然です。
また、3はOPがEditで説明しているとおり自然です。
[更]{さら}に、3と4を比べたときは3の方が自然です。
私が自然だと判断する理由は、各々の文で、前半の条件に対して後半の状態が起きる[確率]{かくりつ}が高いからだと思います。確率が低いときには、[断定的]{だんていてき}な表現より[曖昧]{あいまい}さを残した表現の方が自然に聞こえるのは当然です。

> 5. 金額いかんでは、その仕事を引き受けないこともありません
> 6. 金額いかんでは、その仕事を引き受けなくもないです。
> 7. 金額いかんでは、その仕事を引き受けないこともあります。

質問の回答とは少し違いますが、OPがInternetで見つけたとする5は論理的には間違いはないのですが、奇妙に聞こえます。もし、仕事を引き受けるなら6のように言うのが普通です。また、もし仕事を引き受けないのなら7と言うでしょうね。

---

EDIT

> 1. 最近とても疲れやすいので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともある。
> 2. 最近とても疲れやすいので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むかもしれない。
> 3. ずっと前から疲れがちなので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともある。
> 4. ずっと前から疲れがちなので、その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むかもしれない。

Comment: あのですね、、 質問に、「use かもしれない *instead* 」, 「you can answer with the かもしれない format, but wonder why こともある is incorrect」, 「試合が中止になることもある... 試合が中止になるかもしれない」と書かれているでしょう。あなたの回答の1,3番は「その日の体調いかんでは会社を休むこともある」, 2,4番は「その日の体調いかんでは会社を休む**こともあるかもしれない** 」となっていますが、質問者は「Vこともある」vs「Vこともあるかもしれない」を問題にしておられるのではなく、「Vこともある」vs「Vかもしれない」を問題にしておられるのですよ。

Comment: >Chocolateさん　ご指摘のとおり間違いです。訂正しました。

Answer (score 1):

> 最近とても疲れやすいので、その日の体調いかんでは________
> I answered it with : 会社を休むこともある

This is not wrong gramatically, but logically doesn't follow if I get a little nit-picky. I will explain. Your teacher's

会社を休むかもしれない

...is better for sure. The reason why is that you started wtih

最近

which, as you know, is "Lately, these days." So, what follows has to be converstaion about recent events and decisions on near future. "I might take a day off" is a possible decision coming up very soon. Like, I might eat burger tonight or maybe I'll go for ramen. Something you decide, say, within 48 hours and you are telling your buddy about your thoughts.

HOWEVER.

Since you said

会社を休むこともある

You are speaking to general decision making, explaining who you are as a person, a personality, your MO. So, it has nuance of saying "I'm the kind of guy/girl that skips work sometimes."

Your teacher is saying that the link "Tired lately" --> "routelinely skipping work" is wried, I'd say in any language. "Tired lately" --> "might take a day off" follows better logically.

Though, since it's obvious, given the context most native speaker would be kind and say that "I see what you mean." But using the form in the first way might give away that you may not be a native speaker of the language.